# "Illegal" implementation of generic method : Why don't I get any compilation error?

Tags: java, generics, typechecking

I've got an interface containing a method with this signature :

```java
<P extends MergeProperty<T> & RestartApplicant> List<P> loadPropertiesFrom(T p1, T p2);
```

Basically, `MergeProperty` is a class which does **NOT** implement `RestartApplicant`, and `RestartApplicant` is a functional interface containing a method that does not really matter for the understanding of this problem.

Here is the catch. When I create a class implementing this interface, Java allows me to run **without any compiling error** the following code :

```java
public class MyImplementation implements MyInterfacePreviouslyDescribed {

    @Override
    public List<MergeProperty<MathObject>> loadPropertiesFrom(MathObject p1, MathObject p2) {
        return Arrays.asList(
            // some random instances of MergeProperty that do not implement RestartApplicant
        );
    }
}
```

Obviously, I don't respect the restrictions of the implementation there. Given this signature, the list I return using `Arrays.asList(...)` does **NOT** need to contain elements that implement `RestartApplicant`. Remember, `MergeProperty` doesn't implement `RestartApplicant`. So this will most likely end up causing some casting error somewhere.

Still, I get a warning :

```
Type safety: The return type List<Main.MergeProperty<Main.MathObject>> for
loadPropertiesFrom(Main.MathObject, Main.MathObject) (...) needs unchecked
conversion to conform to List<Main.MergeProperty&Main.RestartApplicant> from the
type Main.Test<Main.MathObject>
```

My question is: why do I only get a warning? It seems to me that I should not be able to compile my code. Is there any particular reason for that?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

After playing a little with my code, I figured that if I moved the "generics declaration" to the class level, which would lead to :

```java
interface MyInterfacePreviouslyDescribed<T, P extends MergeProperty<T> & RestartApplicant>
```

instead of just

```java
interface MyInterfacePreviouslyDescribed<T>
```

and obviously

```java
List<P> loadPropertiesFrom(T p1, T p2);
```

instead of

```java
<P extends MergeProperty<T> & RestartApplicant> List<P> loadPropertiesFrom(T p1, T p2);
```

then I actually **get** a compilation error if I try the same "illegal" implementation as before. It seems even more strange...

Answer (score 2):

You can even do:

```
    @Override
    public List<String> loadPropertiesFrom(MathObject p1, MathObject p2) {
        return Arrays.asList(
            // some random instances of MergeProperty that do not implement RestartApplicant
        );
    }
```

in the first case. This is because the overridden method is *not* generic and *erasure* for these is going to be `List`. Why is this allowed? I frankly don't know, may be something to do with backwards compatibility.

In your second example, it seems it should really be:

```
interface MyInterfacePreviouslyDescribed<T, P extends MergeProperty<T> & RestartApplicant> {
```

and in the implementation you are forcing the types to be correct. Actually, the second example is the intuitive one - as it does not compile; and that *is* expected. The first one, on the other hand relies on some compatibility rule for non-generic methods that allows to override to the same erasure.

Comment: Interesting. The second example seems indeed more intuitive after all. And yeah, the missing "T" in the latter was a typo